How to access OpenType vertical variant from XeTeX
I apologize if this turns out to be more of a font question than a LaTeX question.  I have no MWE because I don't have anything working yet.  I'm working on a new summation type operator that needs to appear at one size inline and a larger size in display mode.  I started by creating two glyphs of the appropriate sizes.  It is an OpenType font so I named the second glyph after the first, but with a .v1 suffix (I'm following the method used in TeX Gyre Termes Math).  Then I created an entry in the MATH table (Vertical Variants subsection) with Glyph: summationtwo and Pre-Built Larger Variants: summationtwo summationtwo.v1. Obviously, something more than this is required, but I do not know whether it is something that goes in the font file itself or something that XeTeX does, perhaps in unicode-math, which I am not yet using.  I do not want to go there yet.  I will get there, but one step at a time, which I want to thoroughly understand before moving on.  So the general question is: what is required to get vertical variants to work in XeTeX?
BTW: The only thing that I deliberately did differently from the example TeX Gyre Termes Math font is that I put the larger variant glyph in the PUA so that it actually has a Unicode point and can be accessed independently if desired.  But I don't know why that should matter.
Edit: Here is a MWE that only tries to load my font as the math font.  Instead, I get LatinModernMath-Regular.  If I substitute an existing math font in place of mine, that gets loaded.  So what is wrong with mine?  It has very few glyphs.  Is this the problem?  It has the default FontForge MATH table as I have only edited the Vertical Variant.  Is that the problem?
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\DeclareSymbolFont@m@dropped{15}{255}{\typeout{patched}}{\ERROR}
\makeatother
\setmainfont[Scale=1,Mapping=tex-text]{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setsansfont[Scale=0.9,Mapping=tex-text]{TeX Gyre Heros}
\setmonofont[Scale=0.9]{Consolas}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{termes4math-r.otf}
\begin{document}
    This is a test: $\sum_{n=1}^{k}a^k=0$.
    \begin{align*}
        \sum_{n=1}^{k}a^k&=0\\
    \end{align*}
\end{document}


if you are not using unicode-math then how do you use and test your new font??

@UlrikeFischer I have accumulated a lot of personalized LaTeX code to do this, with help from people in this forum.  It works well for standard glyphs, but now that I am setting my sights on vertical and horizontal variants, I need to learn new functionality.

well if your code works with an existing open type math font then the math table in your own font is probably wrong.

@UlrikeFischer I have not required a MATH table until now.  The personalized code that I am referring to just pulls individual glyphs out of the font and makes them accessible in LaTeX (XeTeX actually), either with an alphabetic character, or one of the Greek LaTeX commands, or some new command that I devise.  I have been using MathTime Pro 2 for math, but I am trying to move away from that.  But I like the way my documents look so I am shooting for an OpenType solution that looks the same or very close.  So my MATH table at this point only has that single variant substitution.

you need to decide whether you want a traditional tfm based math font setup or an opentype math layout. In the former case the math table isn't used at all, in the latter the math table has to supply essentially all the traditional tex math layout parmeters

@DavidCarlisle Well, I have seen the writing on the wall for a while, which is why I am trying to move to an OpenType solution.  My understanding is that a) Adobe is no longer supporting Type 1 fonts, which I believe require the tfm files, and that b) OpenType does not use tfm.  If this is correct, then my decision seems justified.  But I want the end result to mimic the output I was getting with mtpro2 as much as legally possible.  So I am taking it a small step at a time.

So, if this is indeed a font issue, what besides the vertical variants entry in the MATH table is required for this to happen automatically?  I am getting the regular glyph regardless of whether I use it in text mode or display mode, so I just presumed that something else was necessary.

sometimes small steps are not possible, when paragliding off a cliff you need to take a big jump, or decide not to go. You haven't given much of a clue as to your current setup but if you are using a tfm based math layout the math table won't be consulted at all as far as I know. If you set the math fam to be an opentype font with a math table that table needs to specify all the parameters. (also I'd use luatex rather than xetex for any new projects, although that probably isn't the issue here)

@DavidCarlisle When you say all of the parameters, can you be more specific?  For things like superscript and subscript offsets and heights, I think I can get that up and running in short order.  But I am building the font simultaneously and I need to be able to test it as I go.  It is missing most of its glyphs right now, which I thought would cause all sorts of errors if I loaded it as the math font.  If not, I guess I can go that route.  Will this work?

sorry you really haven't given enough information for anyone to say if anything will work but tex needs around 22 parameters to set up its math layout and they need to come from the tfm files for the fonts in fam 2 and 3 or they need to come from the Math table of an opentype font If you ar using tfm fonts in fam 2 and 3 I don't think the math table in any other fonts will be consulted so your larger variants probably won't be used, but it's a while since I checked the details here

@DavidCarlisle I have been loading mtpro2 as the math font, using XeTeX with OpenType text fonts, and substituting a lot of glyphs from other fonts as needed.  As you have pointed out more than once, I need to get away from mtpro2 and use unicode-math but I am not sure how to make the switch and still develop the new font.  I just tried loading my font as the math-font and unicode-math must have somehow known it wouldn't work because it is substituting LatinModernMath-Regular, which I think is the default behavior.  So that means it will use the MATH table from that font.

@DavidCarlisle Probably time for a new question, but is it the absence of glyphs in the font that is causing unicode-math to default to LatinModernMath-Regular or the absence of a properly configured MATH table?

latin modern is the default font for unicode-math, why some code you have not shown has not changed that default I don't see how anyone can answer.

@DavidCarlisle I have added a MWE that at least shows that my font is not getting loaded as the math font.  I cannot say that I really expected it to.  I am amazed that unicode-math, rather than displaying a long list of errors as I expected, just quietly substitutes a working font and moves on.  But my problem of testing my font remains.

Actually, it doesn't even show that; you're just taking my word for it.  But I hope that it's something simple like my having something in the wrong order.

Change your example to something that we can use eg change termes4math-r.otf to use a clearly different math font, say Noto Sans Math. If the example then demonstrates your issue thare is an error in your tex declarations we can debug. If it doesn't then the issue is in the font you have not shown, and no answer is possible without more information.

@DavidCarlisle I already know that if I replace it termes4math-r.otf with an existing math font, that the existing font will be loaded instead of Latin Modern.  So, I know something is wrong with my font.  I just don't know what exactly--yet.  I filled in the parameters in the MATH table with the same ones from TeX Gyre Termes Math and it still will not load my font.  So my assumption at this point is that unicode-math must require some minimum number of glyphs available (that is, certain blocks must be filled), which I am certain mine does not.

I think it only requires the math script to be set and a math table to be present (but it gives an error if that isn't the case) but as you have not shown  font and say there is no error, it is impossible to guess what your issue is.

My next move is to take a working math font and use it as a template.  Then I will replace the glyphs one by one or block by block, adjusting the metrics as necessary until it is complete.  I'll report if that works.

Okay, that worked.  Hopefully, I will figure out down the road what the problem was.  I am tempted to make a copy of this file and start deleting blocks of glyphs and accompanying entries in the MATH table until I either get this problem again or get down to my glyphs only.

I determined the problem with why Latin Modern was being loaded by default.  When I was generating the font, I did not have the OpenType checkbox checked in FontForge.  Evidently, this is what includes the tables.  I guess the main question is essential answered by @Davidcarlisle: the OpenType features require the font to be loaded as the math font which in turn requires unicode-math'.
